# Does Google Maps SDK for iOS display 3D maps?

Tags: ios, google-maps, 3d, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have integrated Google Maps SDK to an iOS application and I would like to display 3D Satellite maps. According to the documentation this should work just directly. I can tilt the view, but the displayed map remains flat (i.e. mountains do not show up in 3D as they do in Google Earth).

I have been searching extensively for this, but found no reference or mentioning whether it actually works or does not. Does anybody know whether the 3D maps (google SDK) do work on iOS and I am just hitting some limitation/wrong switch or whether they do not work?

Answer (score 0):

As of SDK v1.8, tilted layers do appear to have some 3D elevation effects, but it's more subtle than Google Earth typically is.